# Why do I still get an implicit conversion warning after explicitly converting all values to varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm getting an implicit conversion warning from the below but I can't figure out why. Everything is being explicitly converted to `VARCHAR`.

The warning says:

> type conversion in expression (CONVERT(varchar(30),datepart(year,CONVERT_IMPLICIT(datetime,[GrantDate],0)),0)) may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query plan choice

I thought I might need to explicitly convert GrantDate from `SMALLDATETIME` to `DATETIME` inside the `YEAR` function but that did not remove the warning. I'd be willing to let the issue slide as I don't think it has any impact on performance but the client scans all our queries and rejects them if they contain implicit conversions.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(DAY(GrantDate), 'D2')) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(GrantDate, 'MMM')) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, GrantDate))) AS MyDateKey
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve here? The above is most certainly overly complicated.

Comment: Why all the format() functions?  ...   If you must  try   Select format(getdate(),'dd-MMM-yyyy')

Comment: Though, for that `CONVERT(varchar(11),GrantDate,106)` would likely be better too, @JohnCappelletti, as `FORMAT` tends to be a pretty slow function

Comment: Also, format() will return a string.  There is no need for convert(varchar,...) .

Comment: @DaleK the all caps `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` part in the warning.

Comment: @Larnu it's being stitched together with other fields to create a unique identifier. However I've isolated the implicit conversion to this line.

Comment: What is the datatype of `GrantDate`?

Comment: @Larnu format() is a double edged sword.  Some great functionality at the cost of performance.   If used sparingly ... I see little harm.  Furthermore, OP seems to be looking for a specific format, while convert(...,106) is close, this would require a replace()

Comment: @Larnu GrantDate is of type `SMALLDATETIME`